# how can i limit the returned items into my second object

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, doctrine-orm

suppose that i have an object Discussions contain many messages.
the question here that i want to return a list discussion with the last message.

here is my code in my controller

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:User')
        ->findOneBy(array("email" => $username));
$current_user = $user->getId();
$discussionList = $user->getDiscussions();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(array("id" => 'DESC'));
$last_list = $discussionList->matching($criteria);

$page = 1;
$page = $request->get('page');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
$last_list, /* query NOT result */
$request->query->getInt('page', $page)/*page number*/,
$request->query->get('limit', 5)/*limit per page*/);
$page_number= $pagination->getCurrentPageNumber();
$item_number_per_page= $pagination->getItemNumberPerPage();
$number_page= $pagination->getTotalItemCount()/5;


$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null);
$serializer = new Serializer([new DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer]);


$data = $serializer->normalize([$pagination,
        array('current page'=>$page_number,
        'item number per page'=>$item_number_per_page,
            'total page' =>$number_page)],
        'json', ['groups' => 'discussion']);
return new JsonResponse($data,200);
```

and here the returned response

```
{
        "id": 8,
        "createdAt": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
        "message": [
            {
                "id": 29,
                "contenu": "hello from id 68",
                "created_at": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
                "etat": 0,
                "user": {
                    "id": 68,
                    "first_name": "auxiliaire",
                    "second_name": "second_auxiliaire",
                    "profil_photo": "ae2d92cf6bf904f13153c3cc38fa1bbd.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 30,
                "contenu": "hello again, just i test this shit",
                "created_at": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-04T00:00:00+00:00",
                "etat": 0,
                "user": {
                    "id": 68,
                    "first_name": "auxiliaire",
                    "second_name": "second_auxiliaire",
                    "profil_photo": "ae2d92cf6bf904f13153c3cc38fa1bbd.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 31,
                "contenu": "hello from user 69",
                "created_at": "2019-12-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                "etat": 0,
                "user": {
                    "id": 69,
                    "first_name": "auxiliaire",
                    "second_name": "second_auxiliaire",
                    "profil_photo": "5628bb30b74cc1946c12e7342e78e256.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 32,
                "contenu": "hello from user 69",
                "created_at": "2019-12-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-12-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                "etat": 0,
                "user": {
                    "id": 68,
                    "first_name": "auxiliaire",
                    "second_name": "second_auxiliaire",
                    "profil_photo": "ae2d92cf6bf904f13153c3cc38fa1bbd.jpg"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

so my probleme here how can i limit the returned response of the message object.
someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `serialization groups` and `doctrine criteria`. Just will add some serialization group to fields except `$messages` and create method called `getLastMessage` with this serialization group. In this case serializer will ignore your `$messages` filed and will add lastMessage field. Method will look like this

```
    /**
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("lastMessage")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"someGroup"})
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function getLastMessage(): ?Message
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->orderBy(['created_at' => Criteria::DESC])
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;

        $result = $this->messages->matching($criteria);

        return !$result->isEmpty() ? $result->first() : null;
    }
```

Comment: yeah i just test your solution, it work reallly, but i prefer do it in my controller with my groupe serialization cause the field $messages return all the object that i need.
thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but i just find anohter way to get the list of discussion with the last message.
it loock like this, sorry i didn't test your method but i think it's good.

```
 $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('App:User')
        ->findOneBy(array("email" => $username));
    $discussion = new Discussions();
    $current_user = $user->getId();
    $discussionList = $user->getDiscussions();


    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(array("id" => 'DESC'));
    $last_list = $discussionList->matching($criteria);

    foreach ($last_list as $discussion)
    {
        $last_message = $discussion->getMessage()->last();
        foreach ($discussion->getMessage() as $message)
        {
            if($message != $last_message)
                $discussion->removeMessage($message);
        }
    }
    $page = 1;
    $page = $request->get('page');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $last_list, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', $page)/*page number*/,
        $request->query->get('limit', 5)/*limit per page*/);
    $page_number= $pagination->getCurrentPageNumber();
    $item_number_per_page= $pagination->getItemNumberPerPage();
    $number_pagee= $pagination->getTotalItemCount()/5;
    $number_page =round($number_pagee, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
    $all_item_number = $pagination->getTotalItemCount();

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null);
    $serializer = new Serializer([new DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer]);

    $data = $serializer->normalize([$pagination,
        array('current page'=>$page_number,
            'item number per page'=>$item_number_per_page,
            'total page' =>$number_page,
            'total item' =>$all_item_number)],
        'json', ['groups' => 'discussion']);
    return new JsonResponse($data,200);
```